# How do i make my character move in the direction of the camera (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity I want to make it so that when I hold w, instead of going in a single direction I want it to go forward in the direction of my camera how do I do that? (Sorry I'm new to unity)

EDIT: The movement script is:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    void Update() {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0,     Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
             moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @lockstock, the direction the camera is facing can be retrieved from its transform. Here is an example below if you want to know how to use it.

```c#
public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    // Drag & Drop the camera in this field, in the inspector
    public Transform cameraTransform ;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    void Update() {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = cameraTransform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This scripts **works** without any error. I've tested it in Unity myself.

Answer (score 0):

The forward direction of the camera is obtained by using `Camera.main.transform.forward`

Answer (score 0):

turn your player so the blue axis is facing the same direction as the blue axis on the camera. then drag and drop the camera onto the player. now when you move the player, the camera will follow, and stay behind the player

Answer (score 0):

This is part of my Solution to this problem.

I used with a thing very similar to solution of @Hellium

```
    protected GameObject  focalPoint;
    protected PlayerInputs playerInputs;
    protected float speed = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 currentMovementValues;
    CharacterController characterController;
    private void Awake() {
        playerInputs        = new PlayerInputs();
        characterController = this.gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();  
        focalPoint          = GameObject.Find("FocalPoint");
        playerInputs.CharacterController.Move.started   += onMovementInput;
        playerInputs.CharacterController.Move.canceled  += onMovementInput;
        playerInputs.CharacterController.Move.performed += onMovementInput;
    }
    
    void onMovementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {
            Vector2 currentInputValues  = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            currentMovementValues.x     = currentInputValues.x;
            currentMovementValues.z     = currentInputValues.y;
    }
    private void Start() {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(focalPoint.transform.forward, focalPoint.transform.up);
    }
    private void Update() {
        handleAnimation();
        characterController.Move(moveDirection() * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    Vector3 moveDirection() {
        return focalPoint.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(-currentMovementValues.x, 0f, currentMovementValues.z)) * speed;
    }

    private void OnEnable() {
        playerInputs.CharacterController.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable() {
        playerInputs.CharacterController.Disable();
    }
```

I hope this solution can be useful to you.